# ClientSide Validiation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am new to asp.net programming.

I have the following template field inside a gridView.

```
<asp:TemplateField
    HeaderText="Delete"
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton
            runat="server"
            ID="lnkDelete"
            OnCommand="lnkDelete_Command"
            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ItemID")%>'
            OnClientClick="showDeleteVerifiction()"
         </asp:LinkButton>
....
```

So right now, my delete button works in my gridView. You can assume that the function lnkDelete_Command deletes the item with the corresponding `ItemID`.

I would like to add in a client-side (JS/Jquery) check to be able to prompt the user if he would like to delete the item, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

After looking at some tutorials, I have tried the following:

```
showDeleteVerification = function()
{
    alert("not letting this pass");
    return false;
}
```

However, the item is still deleted when I click OK

Comment: Are you getting the alert window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `client` click event as use [**confirm**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) javascript function. To bind onclick javascript event you need to [**OnClientClick**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) provided by asp.net.

The confirm function will return `true` or `false` for ok or cancel. If true is return your will have postback and for false there will be no postback.

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');"
```

If you want to call a function as you mentioned in question:

```
<asp:LinkButton
        runat="server"
        ID="lnkDelete"
        OnCommand="lnkDelete_Command"
        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ItemID")%>'
        OnClientClick="return showDeleteVerifiction()"
</asp:LinkButton>

function showDeleteVerification()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete");        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use confirm to achieve your result:

instead of `alert` use `confirm`

```
showDeleteVerification = function()
{
    confirm("not letting this pass");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried it with alert("") and it worked after I did `OnClientClick="return showDeleteVerification()"` I was missing the return statement